# I need to get Shop details of Shopify Websites

Tags: html, web-scraping, shopify, data-extraction, shopify-api

I know of the endpoint `/products.json` but it only returns the products info.

I need a way to get the shop info like `email`, `contact number`, `address`, `manager (or any) name` etc.

I don't think scraping is an option as all websites have different structure. But I'm all ears for any suggestions.

An example website [gymshark.com](https://www.gymshark.com). Its products: https://www.gymshark.com/products.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your Admin API access token to make a GQL query on the shop resource. Or make a RestAPI call to Shop. If all you have is a storefront API token, then you can call for the shop resource as well.